# Angular PDF View error - disableCreateObjectURL

Tags: angular, pdf.js, pdf-viewer

I am trying to add the `ng2-pdf-viewer` to my Angular 8 project, but I cannot seem to make that happen.  I install the package, then add it to my `app.module.ts` like so:

```
import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';

@NgModule({
  imports: [..., PdfViewerModule],
})
```

As soon as I do this, and my project reloads, I get the following error:

```
pdf_viewer.js:2848 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'disableCreateObjectURL' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (pdf_viewer.js:2848)
    at __w_pdfjs_require__ (pdf_viewer.js:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (pdf_viewer.js:234)
    at __w_pdfjs_require__ (pdf_viewer.js:52)
    at pdf_viewer.js:116
    at pdf_viewer.js:119
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (pdf_viewer.js:25)
    at Object../node_modules/pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer.js (pdf_viewer.js:32)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/fesm5/ng2-pdf-viewer.js (ng2-pdf-viewer.js:128)
```

I tried installing `@types/pdfjs-dist`, `pdfjs-dist` and `tslib` but the error does not seem to want to go away.

I don't know if I am missing something or if it is clashing with another package that I am using.   I have no more hair left to pull out.

Answer (score 0):

"ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.3.2",
"@types/pdfjs-dist": "2.1.4",
"core-js": "3.6.5",
"url": "^0.11.0",
"webpack": "4.43.0",

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-pdf-viewer-u1sbr7?file=package.json